# How can I display image form every album with an albumId?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to insert display pics from a JSON. In this JSON I have photo {id, title and , url}. In every album with the URL, every album have an id and every pic have an album Id. I have to display every pic in the right album.

How can I do it?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlbumService } from '../../../services/album/album.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../../user';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/users/user.service';
import { Photo } from '../../../photo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details.post',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css'],

})
export class AlbumDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  album$: object;
  user: object;
  photos: Photo[];

  constructor(private data: AlbumService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {
    this.photos = new Array<Photo>();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDetailAlbum();
    this.getPhoto();
  }
  private getDetailAlbum() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = parseInt(params.id, 30);
      if (id) {
        this.getDetail(id);
        this.getUserDetail(id);
      }
    });
  }
  private getDetail(postId: number) {
    this.data.getDetail(postId).subscribe(
      data => this.album$ = data
    );
  }
  private getUserDetail(albumId: number) {
    this.userService.getDetail(albumId).subscribe(
      data => this.user = data
    );
  }


  private getPhoto() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const albumId = parseInt(params.albumId, 30);
      if (albumId) {
        this.getPhotos(albumId);
      }
    });
  }
  private getPhotos(albumId: number) {
    this.data.getPhotoByAlbum(albumId).subscribe(
      data => this.photos = data
    );
  }

}


my service
<!-- this is my service -->


import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Album } from '../../album';
import {Photo} from '../../photo';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlbumService {
  private AlbumUrl = 'api/User';
  album = new EventEmitter<Album>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getList() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums');
  }
  getListByUser(userId): Observable<Album[]> {
    return this.http.get<Album[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/?userId=' + userId);
  }
  getDetail(albumId) {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/' + albumId);
  }
  getPhotoByAlbum(albumId): Observable<Photo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Photo[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=' + albumId);
  }

  set(album) {
    console.log(album);

  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="album$">
  <h1>
    <a routerLink="/details/{{user.id}}">{{ user.name }}</a>
  </h1>
  <ul class="container">
    <li>
      <strong>title:</strong> {{album$.title}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div *ngFor="let photo of photos">
    <div class="photo">
      <div>photo.title </div>
      <img src={{photo.url}}>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

if some one could help me or give me any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[src]` for image binding.

```
<img [src]="photo.url">
```

Comment: could you check if the code is right in the ts file ?